# Increment ID by getting the last record id from mysqli table

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to get the last Employee ID from my Sqli table, increment the id retrieved from the table and insert the new value into the table along with the new record.

The code is not working as the table is not getting updated.

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="brn" placeholder="Branch"/>
<input type="text" name="nam" placeholder="Enter Name"/>
<input type="submit" name="insert">
<?php
$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['insert']))
{
    $brn = $_POST['brn'];
    $nam = $_POST['nam'];
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM emp";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$qry);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $empid= $row["empid"];
    $empid++;

    $query = "INSERT INTO `emp`(`brn`,`nam`,'empid') VALUES ('$brn','$nam','$empid')";
    mysqli_query($db,$query);

    mysqli_close($db);
}
?>
</form>
```

Comment: You can make `empid` field as [auto increment](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp). You never do such a thing unless some exceptional situation arises.

Comment: As @Abhishek says, use an auto increment field or create a AFTER INSERT TRIGGER where you update the id field.

Comment: you can also try :  "SELECT max(empid) FROM emp";

Comment: And what happens instead? Is there any error message given?

Answer (score 0):

You need some changes in your code.
You are selecting the **first "EmpId"** instead of the last one and if you are having the column empid as primary key, it will show the error of primary key violation. 
Therefore change your query to somewhat this:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM emp order by empid desc limit 1";
```

It will ***return one row.***

And, if you just need the *last empid* then i would suggest you to go with only:

```
$qry = "SELECT empid FROM emp order by empid limit 1";
```

This is ***more resource effective query.***

****Happy Coding.****

Comment: I have modified my code as suggested to be be resource effective. But still the data is not getting  inserted into the table.

Comment: Then I would suggest you echo your insert query on your webpage before the actual SQL is fired. And then copy the query formed and paste and fire it on phpmyadmin directly to find the error..

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. I hope it will help you.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `emp`(`brn`,`nam`,'empid') VALUES ('$brn','$nam','$empid')";
if(mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);
    echo "Records inserted successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```